# Reading Text file on Windows PC shared location from Adroid C#

Tags: c#, android

So currently I got a text file in a shared folder on my PC and I want to access it from android Phone.

Here is the code I'm using but it's not finding the file.

```
 void ReadFile()
    {
        TextView file = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.fileview);
        string filepath = @"\\192.168.8.102\Sharedtest\test.txt";

        if (!File.Exists(filepath))
        {
            file.Text = "No File Found";
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(filepath, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                file.Text = $"{line}\n";
            }

        }
    }
```

File is shared and no firewall.

If someone can just point me in a direction that would be great.

I don't want to download file I just want to read content.

Comment: You should use a library that understands the samba protocoll.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FileStream with FileMode.Open. check Microsoft [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.open?view=netcore-3.1).

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open))
{
    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    UTF8Encoding temp = new UTF8Encoding(true);
    while (fs.Read(b, 0, b.Length) > 0)
    {
        file.Text = temp.GetString(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: it still does not find the file   >>>>   **System.IO.FileNotFoundException:** 'Could not find file "/\\192.168.8.102\Sharedtest\test.txt"'

Comment: do want to add using Xamarin blank app in VS2019 . tested all code (mine and yours in consoleApp (.net framework) then it works . but not from android